# summing over a list of int overflow(?) python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's consider a list of large integers, for example one given by:

```
def primesfrom2to(n):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188#3035188
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    sieve = np.ones(n/3 + (n%6==2), dtype=np.bool)
    sieve[0] = False
    for i in xrange(int(n**0.5)/3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[      ((k*k)/3)      ::2*k] = False
            sieve[(k*k+4*k-2*k*(i&1))/3::2*k] = False
    return np.r_[2,3,((3*np.nonzero(sieve)[0]+1)|1)]

primesfrom2to(2000000)
```

I want to calculate the sum of that, and the expected result is 142913828922. 
But if I do:

```
sum(primesfrom2to(2000000))
```

I get 1179908154, which is clearly wrong. The problem is that I have an int overflow, but I don't understand why. Let's me explain.Consider this testing code:

```
a=primesfrom2to(2000000)
b=[float(i) for i in a]
c=[long(i) for i in a]
sumI=0
sumF=0
sumL=0
m=0
for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):
    m=m+1
    sumI=sumI+i
    sumF=sumF+j
    sumL=sumL+k
    print sumI,sumF,sumL
    if sumI<0:
        print i,m
        break
```

I found out that the first integer overflow is happening at a[i=20444]=225289

If I do:

```
>>> sum(a[:20043])+225289
-2147310677
```

But if I do:

```
>>> sum(a[:20043])
2147431330
>>> 2147431330+225289
2147656619L
```

What's happening? Why such a different behaviour? Why can't sum switch automatically to long type and give the correct result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the types of your results.  You are summing a numpy array, which is using numpy datatypes, which can overflow.  When you do `sum(a[:20043])`, you get a numpy object back (some sort of `int32` or the like), which overflows when added to another number.  When you manually type in the same number, you're creating a Python builtin `int`, which can auto-promote to `long`.  Numpy arrays cannot autopromote like Python builtin types, because the array type (and its memory layout) have to be fixed when the array is created.  This makes operations much faster at the expense of type flexibility.

You may be able to get around the problem by using a different datatype (like `np.int64`) instead of `np.bool`.  However, it depends how big your numbers are.  A simple example:

```
# Python types ok
>>> 2**62
4611686018427387904L
>>> 2**63
9223372036854775808L

# numpy types overflow
>>> np.int64(2)**62
4611686018427387904
>>> np.int64(2)**63
-9223372036854775808
```

Your example works correctly for me on 64-bit Python, so I guess you're using 32-bit Python.  If you can use 64-bit types you will be able to get past the limit you found, but as my example shows you will eventually overflow 64-bit ints too if your numbers get super huge.

Comment: I never thought that np.int where different from python int. Good to know :-)

Comment: This is correct, and just to add to why no auto promote, its (mostly) because of the great speed increases you get by using the fixed data size which the processors are optimized for. numpy likes to be fast.

Comment: @BrenBarn, is this system dependent somehow as I get the correct answer running the OP's code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, it will depend on whether you're running 64-bit or 32-bit Python.